# DryIoc adapter for Akka.NET

Tags: ioc-container, akka.net, dryioc

I work with the Akka.net. I want to use the DryIoc as an IoC-container, but there is no ready-made using adapters for the actor system in the Akka. The [documentation](https://getakka.net/articles/actors/di-core.html) says that to use a custom IoC-container, I need to implement `IDependencyResolver`. Looked for the libraries for AutoFac and CastleWindsor as examples, I made a DependencyResolver for DryIoc:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Concurrent;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

using Akka.Actor;
using Akka.DI.Core;

using DryIoc;

namespace Akka.DI.DryIoc
{
    public sealed class DryIocDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver, INoSerializationVerificationNeeded
    {
        private readonly IContainer container;
        private readonly ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type> typeCache;
        private readonly ActorSystem system;
        private readonly ConditionalWeakTable<ActorBase, IResolverContext> references;

        public DryIocDependencyResolver(IContainer container, ActorSystem system)
        {
            this.container  = container
                ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("container");

            this.system     = system
                ?? throw new ArgumentNullException("system");

            this.typeCache  = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Type>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
            this.references = new ConditionalWeakTable<ActorBase, IResolverContext>();

            this.system.AddDependencyResolver(this);
        }

        public Func<ActorBase> CreateActorFactory(Type actorType)
            => () =>
                {
                    var context = this.container.OpenScope();
                    var key     = (ActorBase)context.Resolve(actorType);
                    this.references.Add(key, context);
                    return key;
                };

        public Type GetType(string actorName)
        {
            var type = actorName.GetTypeValue();
            if (type is null)
                type = this.container.GetServiceRegistrations()
                                     .Where(registration =>
                                        registration.ImplementationType.Name.Equals(actorName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                     .Select(registration =>
                                        registration.ImplementationType)
                                     .FirstOrDefault();

            this.typeCache.TryAdd(actorName, type);

            return this.typeCache[actorName];
        }

        public Props Create<TActor>()
            where TActor : ActorBase
            => this.Create(typeof(TActor));

        public Props Create(Type actorType)
            => this.system.GetExtension<DIExt>().Props(actorType);

        public void Release(ActorBase actor)
        {
            if (!this.references.TryGetValue(actor, out IResolverContext lifetimeScope))
                return;

            lifetimeScope.Dispose();
            this.references.Remove(actor);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I'm not sure that everything is done correctly. I especially doubt the necessity of using the type cache and implementing the GetType method.

Comment: @dadhi, if you will have a bit time, please take a look on this question

Comment: I am not a specialist in Akka, but from DryIoc perspective is nothing suspicious here.

Comment: As far as I know, the DryIoc has an internal effective caching implementation, with this in mind, is cache dictionary needed here in your opinion? Isn't it an unnecessary "crutch" here?

Comment: It ishard to say, because it is actor to context map, and as far as I wee is optionally used for Release only.

Comment: If it helps someone, I posted the finished solution as a [Akka.DI.DryIoc nuget package ](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Akka.DI.DryIoc).